# How do I add a C file from my computer to my Github clone repository so i can send it to the actual repository on Github?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, terminal, vagrant

I want to add a file (dogs.c) to my private cloned repository (vagrant@ubuntu2204:~/github-repository-username) which was made in Vagrant. I then want to use git add/git commit/git push to send it to the actual repository. dogs.c already exists in /Users/username/folder but I cannot figure out how to move the file into this cloned repository since it doesn't exist in my finder.

I understand that it would be simpler to just go to github.com and add the files but I am learning to use the terminal.

Comment: When you say "made in Vagrant", do you mean that the repo is in a virtual machine?